# Keep logged user in memory from database - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing web app with spring security, I have already default security implementation it works fine, but I have question about getting data from database. How can I keep information from database without executing query to database everytime?

Look at this. User is my entity class, but for me it is not effective to retrive data from database everytime. Everytime I refresh that `/welcome` it will execute query, I'm using Spring data jpa so it's fine but does not make sense since there is no change in database. So what I want to do is to keep user and retrive his data from db once in my app. Is there any way to do it?

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/userpanel")
    public String userpanel(Model model, Principal principal){

        String loggedUserName = principal.getName();
        Optional<User> user = userService.findByUserName(loggedUserName);
        if(user.isPresent()){
            model.addAttribute("user", user.get());
        }

        return "userpanel";
    }
```

Comment: You can use spring cache to store data you receive from database for a while.
beside spring cache you can use Redis database.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what a custom `UserDetails` object is for. Make your `User` entity implement `UserDetails`, and make your `UserDetailsService` return it.

This way, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` will return your entity. You will also be able to inject it using `@AuthenticationPrincipal`.

This of course assumes that you have not set session creation to `stateless` (i.e. your security provider is not re-authenticating the user for every request).

Just remember that it is bad practice to keep *sensitive* data in memory for a prolonged period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Spring includes its own caching system: https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

To use it, annotate a method that may take while to fetch something from the database with `@Cacheable(String)`

Then, in the application class, you can add the `@EnableCaching` annotation.

---

[Google Guava also has its own caching system.](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained)

Example usage is like so:

```java
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, User>() {
         public Graph load(User user) throws AnyException {
           return loadFromDatabase(user);
         }
       });
```

This will store a maximum of 1000 users in memory and deletes entries when it gets too big. It will also delete entries after 10 minutes.

It acts like a map, but calls the `load(User)` method if the key (user ID) is not present.